# Prove that, relative fluctuations reduce as the square root of the number of identical processes

Tags: statistics, proof-explanation

Prove that,

"Relative fluctuations reduce as the square root of the number of identical processes."

We want to know rigorous and general proof starting from the definition of 'relative fluctuation'.

You can provide us any reference website or any book reference also. Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_fluctuations Just read the first sentence of that, then the answer is the second sentence

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to view the *sample mean* $\bar X = \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ of $n$ random observations as an estimate of mean $\mu$ of the population from which
the observations were sampled. Then the *standard error* of $\bar X$ can
be used as a measure of 'relative fluctuation'.

If the population standard
deviation $\sigma$ is known, then the *standard error* is $SD(\bar X) = \sigma/\sqrt{n}.$ [Most basic probability books have a proof that
$Var(\bar X) = \sigma^2/n,$ from which one gets $SD(\bar X) = \sigma/\sqrt{n}$ by taking square roots.]

If $\sigma$ is unknown, then $\sigma$ can be estimated by
the sample standard deviation $$S = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i - \bar X)^2},$$ so the (estimated) standard error is $S/\sqrt{n}.$ (Sometimes
the word *estimated* is omitted for brevity.)

Either way, the standard error has $\sqrt{n}$ in the denominator, as you say.

The histogram below shows sample means $\bar X$ of 10,000 samples of size $n = 9$
from a normal population with mean $\mu = 100$ and standard deviation
$\sigma = 15.$ The standard deviation of the histogram is $SD(\bar X) =\sigma/\sqrt{n}
= 15/3 = 5.$ The blue curve is the density function of the population.
Roughly speaking, one can say that the histogram for the sample is a third as 'wide' and three
times as 'tall' as density for the population distribution.

[image]

---

*Note:* I don't know the level of your course, so I don't know what kind of
proof is expected. Here is an outline of the proof that $Var(\bar X) = \sigma^2/n:$

$$Var(\bar X) = Var\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)
= \frac{1}{n^2}Var\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)
= \frac{1}{n^2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n Var(X_i)\right) = \frac{1}{n^2}(n\sigma^2)
= \frac{\sigma^2}{n}.$$